# size of hidden layers in network (grid in h2o )

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I ran h2o.grid with the set of different hiperparameters. Below you can see code connected with it:

```
       library(caret)
        library(ROCR)
        library(h2o)
        h2o.init()

    #creditcard <- read.csv("creditcard.csv") #https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud
        as_h2o <- function(df) {
          for (colname in colnames(df)) {
            if (class(df[[colname]]) == "character") {
              df[[colname]] <- as.factor(df[[colname]])
            }
          }
          df <- as.h2o(df)
          df
        }

        creditcard[,-31]<-scale(creditcard[,-31])

        index <- createDataPartition(creditcard$Class, p = 0.3, list = FALSE)
        train.set <- creditcard[-index, -1]
        test.set <- creditcard[index, -1]

    index.valid <- createDataPartition(creditcard$Class, p = 0.2, list = FALSE)
    train.set <- creditcard[-index.valid, -1]
    valid.set <- creditcard[index.valid, -1]

Y = "Class"
        X = colnames(test.set[,-30])     

     hyper_params <- list(
       activation = c("Rectifier", "Maxout", "Tanh", "RectifierWithDropout", "MaxoutWithDropout", "TanhWithDropout"), 
       hidden = list(c(17,16,15), c(19,15,11), c(16,14,12),c(20,15,10),c(25,17,10),c(15,10,5)),
       epochs = c(50, 100, 200),
       l1 = c(0, 0.001,0.00001, 0.0001), 
       l2 = c(0,0.001, 0.00001, 0.0001),
       rate = c(0, 0.1, 0.005, 0.001),
       rate_annealing = c(1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6),
       rho = c(0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999),
       epsilon = c(1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-6, 1e-4),
       momentum_start = c(0, 0.5),
       momentum_stable = c(0.99, 0.5, 0),
       input_dropout_ratio = c(0, 0.1, 0.2),
       max_w2 = c(10, 100, 1000, 3.4028235e+38)
     )

     search_criteria <- list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", 
                             max_models = 100,
                             max_runtime_secs = 900,
                             stopping_tolerance = 0.001,
                             stopping_rounds = 15)

     dl_grid <- h2o.grid(algorithm = "deeplearning", 
                         x = X,
                         y = Y,
                         grid_id = "dl_grid",
                         training_frame = as_h2o(train.set),
                         validation_frame = as_h2o(valid.set),
                         nfolds = 25,                           
                         fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                         hyper_params = hyper_params,
                         search_criteria = search_criteria
     )
```

but in the results I received some unexpected sizes of neural networks that weren't mentioned in the hyper_params, for example: [10, 10, 10, 10], [50, 50, 50].

The whole result:

```
> dl_grid
H2O Grid Details
================

Grid ID: dl_grid 
Used hyper parameters: 
  -  activation 
  -  epochs 
  -  epsilon 
  -  hidden 
  -  input_dropout_ratio 
  -  l1 
  -  l2 
  -  max_w2 
  -  momentum_stable 
  -  momentum_start 
  -  rate 
  -  rate_annealing 
  -  rho 
Number of models: 13 
Number of failed models: 1 

Hyper-Parameter Search Summary: ordered by increasing logloss
             activation             epochs epsilon           hidden
1             Rectifier 24.666234282086002  1.0E-6     [19, 15, 11]
2             Rectifier  27.58637697029444  1.0E-6 [10, 10, 10, 10]
3             Rectifier  20.26209344328687  1.0E-6     [15, 16, 17]
4             Rectifier  18.57634281485049  1.0E-6     [17, 16, 15]
5             Rectifier 50.032621172309156  1.0E-6     [17, 16, 15]
6             Rectifier 50.032621172309156  1.0E-6     [17, 16, 15]
7                Maxout   8.38177768101728  1.0E-4     [20, 15, 10]
8     MaxoutWithDropout 1.6076279182111595  1.0E-8     [17, 16, 15]
9  RectifierWithDropout 0.5012088413637236 1.0E-10     [15, 15, 15]
10 RectifierWithDropout 0.5012088413637236 1.0E-10     [15, 15, 15]
11    MaxoutWithDropout 28.578195951798776  1.0E-4     [12, 13, 12]
12    MaxoutWithDropout 10.073383841883308  1.0E-4     [15, 16, 17]
13 RectifierWithDropout 0.5012088413637236 1.0E-10     [50, 50, 50]
```

Can anyone explain why it happened?

Comment: Hi kuba, thanks for posting a question! Could you post a simple but complete end to end code snippet that we could use to try and reproduce your issue? As well as the version of H2O you are using. Here is an example of what a reproducible code snippet would look like (ignore the fact that the example uses glm) http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/alpha.html#example.

Answer (score 1):

When running H2O grid search you should only see models that use the same number of hidden layers you provided for your grid search. Here is a code example you can run and play around with to see if you can reproduce your issue.

```
#############################################################
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

train = h2o.importFile("https://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/bigdata/laptop/mnist/train.csv.gz")

# Specify the response and predictor columns
y <- "C785"
x <- setdiff(names(train), y)

# Encode the response column as categorical for multinomial classification
train[,y] <- as.factor(train[,y])
test[,y] <- as.factor(test[,y])

# do a random grid search
hidden_opt <- list(c(32,32), c(32,16,8), c(100,100))
l1_opt <- c(1e-4,1e-3)
hyper_params <- list(hidden = hidden_opt, l1 = l1_opt)
search_criteria = list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", 
                       max_models = 10, 
                       seed=123456)



# grid search
model_grid <- h2o.grid("deeplearning", 
                       grid_id = "mygrid_1",
                       hyper_params = hyper_params, 
                       search_criteria = search_criteria,
                       x = x,
                       y = y,
                       distribution = "multinomial", 
                       training_frame = train, 
                       nfolds = 3,
                       score_interval = 2,
                       stopping_rounds = 3,
                       stopping_tolerance = 0.05,
                       stopping_metric = "misclassification")
model_grid

# Output
# H2O Grid Details
# ================
#   
#   Grid ID: mygrid_1 
# Used hyper parameters: 
#   -  hidden 
# -  l1 
# Number of models: 6 
# Number of failed models: 0 
# 
# Hyper-Parameter Search Summary: ordered by increasing logloss
# hidden     l1        model_ids             logloss
# 1  [100, 100] 1.0E-4 mygrid_1_model_0 0.11350390885225858
# 2  [100, 100]  0.001 mygrid_1_model_4 0.13184550642109982
# 3    [32, 32]  0.001 mygrid_1_model_3 0.13869444872607956
# 4 [32, 16, 8]  0.001 mygrid_1_model_5 0.16575514373784073
# 5    [32, 32] 1.0E-4 mygrid_1_model_2 0.17190959951587054
# 6 [32, 16, 8] 1.0E-4 mygrid_1_model_1 0.20832913000853842
```

Notice in the output you will only see models with hidden layers equal to the original values set: c(32,32), c(32,16,8), c(100,100)

Answer (score 0):

Lauren, thank u for your post. Here is an example of credit card fraud detection modeling

```
 hyper_params <- list(
   activation = c("Rectifier", "Maxout", "Tanh", "RectifierWithDropout", "MaxoutWithDropout", "TanhWithDropout"), 
   hidden = list(c(17,16,15), c(19,15,11), c(16,14,12),c(20,15,10),c(25,17,10),c(15,10,5)),
   epochs = c(50, 100, 200),
   l1 = c(0, 0.001,0.00001, 0.0001), 
   l2 = c(0,0.001, 0.00001, 0.0001),
   rate = c(0, 0.1, 0.005, 0.001),
   rate_annealing = c(1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6),
   rho = c(0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999),
   epsilon = c(1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-6, 1e-4),
   momentum_start = c(0, 0.5),
   momentum_stable = c(0.99, 0.5, 0),
   input_dropout_ratio = c(0, 0.1, 0.2),
   max_w2 = c(10, 100, 1000, 3.4028235e+38)
 )

 search_criteria <- list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", 
                         max_models = 100,
                         max_runtime_secs = 900,
                         stopping_tolerance = 0.001,
                         stopping_rounds = 15)

 dl_grid <- h2o.grid(algorithm = "deeplearning", 
                     x = X,
                     y = Y,
                     grid_id = "dl_grid",
                     training_frame = as_h2o(train.set),
                     validation_frame = as_h2o(valid.set),
                     nfolds = 25,                           
                     fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                     hyper_params = hyper_params,
                     search_criteria = search_criteria
 )
```

Comment: thanks for posting this! ( you can also edit your original question if you want to include new information) Since I wasn't able to successfully run your code, I'm going to post a code snippet below. If you can try to reproduce your issue with the code I've posted, feel free to update your question with more details. It will also be a way for me to make sure I understand your question and whether we need to report a bug or not. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, I've changed the question

Comment: Hi, @Lauren have u got a chance to look at this issue?  Sry for interrupting

Comment: @Kuba what is the size of the cluster you are using, and what version of H2O are you using? thanks for the reproducible code snippet!

Comment: @Lauren The version of h2o: 3.20.0.2

Comment: "size of the cluster" - You mean train set? ~200 000 X 30

Comment: @Kuba does this consistently happen? If you upgrade to the latest 3.20.0.7 do you still see this issue? I was not able to reproduce your issue for version 3.20.0.7 my recommendation is that if you consistently see this issue and you see it in version 3.20.0.7 you should create a jira ticket with the code you posted  here http://jira.h2o.ai because this is unexpected behavior.